# Android: How to divide a LinearLayout in unequal parts?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have 2 TextViews, and I want to assign 67% of the space to `title` and the remaining 33% to the `details`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use *android:layout_weight* in the textview

Comment: You have set `weightSum` and `layout_weight` on `LinearLayout` level. Is that to divide `TextView` inside `LinearLayout` or because you want to give `LinearLayout ` half the width of the parent view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `weight sum` on `LinearLayout` as 4 & provide weight to both `TextView` like below:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="4"
android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="@4dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the widths of the `TextView`s as `0dp` and set `layout_weight` as 2 for title `TextView` and `layout_weight` as 1 for description `TextView`.